# A problem about the top and bottom margins of my chapters?

Tags: margins, chapters, book-design

I have a problem that the top margin of my chapters are large while the bottom margins are very small, here is the code I am using for my chapters:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
 \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % For adding List of Tables and List of Figures to Table of Contents
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@headings{%
      \def\@oddfoot{\normalfont\hfil\thepage\hfil}%
      \def\@evenfoot{\normalfont\hfil\thepage\hfil}}
      \def\@evenhead{\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
      \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil%
      \let\@mkboth\markboth
    \def\chaptermark##1{%
      \markboth {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
          \if@mainmatter
            \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
          \fi
        \fi
        ##1}}{}}%
    \def\sectionmark##1{%
      \markright {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
          \thesection. \ %
        \fi
        ##1}}}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{headings}% apply new definitions
  




\begin{document}
   

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}
  {\titleline{}\vspace{5pt}\titleline{}\vspace{1pt}%
  \MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
  {1pc}
  {\titleline{}\vspace{0.5pc}}
  

\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\section{MOTIVATION} 
\end{document}
```

Is there any advice about that? I guess the problem in my code is in this part:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}
  {\titleline{}\vspace{5pt}\titleline{}\vspace{1pt}%
  \MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
  {1pc}
  {\titleline{}\vspace{0.5pc}}
```

I need the top margin to be for example 1.5in and the bottom to be 1 in.

Comment: You can go ahead and set `top=1.5in,bottom=1in,inner=1in,outer=1in` in `geometry` package. remove `margin=1in`.

Comment: The document is a thesis, and it contain an abstract page and a title page and a copyright page in which my margins are correctly adjusted in that pages, my problem starts in the pages that contains the chapter titles only, which is part of my document and not the whole document.@MarkA.Bromuela

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a reduced space between the top margin and the chapter title. In this case you just edit the `\titleformat` command as you mentioned in your question.

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}
  {\titleline{}\vspace{1pt}\titleline{}\vspace{-0.9in}% The negative value here to move chapter title up
  \MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
  {1pc}
  {\titleline{}\vspace{0.5pc}}
```

[image]